# Installing GiftAid v3.04 into CiviCRM v5.17 Drupal 7 PHP 7 - getting dbError

Tags: gift-aid-extension

I'm getting this when I click Install on the Extensions page,

> Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the
> moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider
> with more details about what action you were performing when this
> occurred.
>
> `DB Error: already exists`

From error log:

```
Sep 26 08:40:37  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => exceptionHandler
        )

    [code] => -5
    [message] => DB Error: already exists
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => INSERT INTO civicrm_custom_field (custom_group_id , name , label , data_type , html_type , is_required , is_searchable , is_search_range , weight , is_active , is_view , text_length , note_columns , note_rows , column_name , in_selector ) VALUES ( 2 , 'Eligible_for_Gift_Aid' , 'UK Tax Payer?' , 'Int' , 'Radio' ,  1 ,  1 ,  0 ,  1 ,  1 ,  0 ,  255 ,  60 ,  4 , 'eligible_for_gift_aid' ,  0 )  [nativecode=1062 ** Duplicate entry 'UK Tax Payer?-2' for key 'UI_label_custom_group_id']
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => INSERT INTO civicrm_custom_field (custom_group_id , name , label , data_type , html_type , is_required , is_searchable , is_search_range , weight , is_active , is_view , text_length , note_columns , note_rows , column_name , in_selector ) VALUES ( 2 , 'Eligible_for_Gift_Aid' , 'UK Tax Payer?' , 'Int' , 'Radio' ,  1 ,  1 ,  0 ,  1 ,  1 ,  0 ,  255 ,  60 ,  4 , 'eligible_for_gift_aid' ,  0 )  [nativecode=1062 ** Duplicate entry 'UK Tax Payer?-2' for key 'UI_label_custom_group_id']
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: already exists" code=-5 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler prefix="" info="INSERT INTO civicrm_custom_field (custom_group_id , name , label , data_type , html_type , is_required , is_searchable , is_search_range , weight , is_active , is_view , text_length , note_columns , note_rows , column_name , in_selector ) VALUES ( 2 , 'Eligible_for_Gift_Aid' , 'UK Tax Payer?' , 'Int' , 'Radio' ,  1 ,  1 ,  0 ,  1 ,  1 ,  0 ,  255 ,  60 ,  4 , 'eligible_for_gift_aid' ,  0 )  [nativecode=1062 ** Duplicate entry 'UK Tax Payer?-2' for key 'UI_label_custom_group_id']"]
)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The full error should be in a file in sites/default/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog. Can you edit your question and add the full error?

Comment: It seems like maybe you had it installed already and it didn't get uninstalled? If you aren't using them yet delete the custom fields and group for "Eligible_for_Gift_Aid".